# is browser history part of google profile?

Tags: google-chrome, history

I have been using chrome on a machine I no longer have access to. I would like to access my browsing history. I had assumed it would be downloadable on google takeout along with eg location history and search history, but I don't see it. I know I have had my browsing history sync'd with other devices, which is what led me to think it was part of the cross-device "google profile". But if so, I don't know how to access it if not google takeout. In short, I'd like to access my browsing history given that:

1. I don't have access to the physical machine with the browser so I can't just get the sql file stored on the local file system, and
2. I don't have a machine I can trust enough to get chrome to sync browsing history with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Is Chrome browsing history stored as part of the google profile?

Yes, if you're signed in and have Chrome Sync turned on.

---

#### What's saved in your Web & App Activity

> Activity from Chrome and other apps
>
> When you check the box next to "Include history from Chrome and other
>   apps in your Web & App Activity," Google saves information like:
>
> - Your Chrome browsing history (if you're signed in and have Chrome Sync turned on). This information helps you see more accurate results
>     and suggestions. For example, if you read a lot of articles about your
>     favorite sports team, you might see an option to receive news updates
>     about that team.
> - The apps you use and the data they share with Google. This lets you see things like sites or content that you've looked at in other apps
>     in your Google search results.

Source [Google Web & App Activity](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/54068?)

---

#### Further reading

- [Account History settings](https://support.google.com/accounts/topic/6152259?hl=en&ref_topic=3382254)

Comment: this is close but I was looking for the actual browsing history, whereas what I see in your link is the search history. (it does also store browser navigation one link away from google search results, though, which is helpful.) But if I just navigate to a site that site will show up in my chrome history (ctrl-H) but not in what you linked to. Perhaps the full (ctrl-H) chrome history just isn't part of the google profile (or at least what we're exposed to)?

Comment: @JasonFarnon "Google saves information like: " Your Chrome browsing history (if you're signed in and have Chrome Sync turned on)."

Comment: @JasonFarnon Stored in "Web & App Activity". Answer updated.

Comment: Do you find it to be the case though? I have "Include history from Chrome and other apps in your Web & App Activity" checked in my account history (note from my question I don't have access to a trusted machine so I don't want to turn on syncing in chrome->settings). I visit website A by entering its URL directly and it doesn't show up in Web & App Activity. I then do a google search with website A's domain, click on the search result, and it does show up in Web & App Activity indexed by the google search.

Comment: @JasonFarnon No idea, I haven't tested it. The docs say "if you're signed in **and** have Chrome Sync turned on". You don't have sync turned on as per your comment so it won't show up.

Comment: @JasonFarnon I rarely use chrome (my main browser is firefox) and I don't trust sync either.